# Is it possible to align a div based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a div which I have set to `align="right"`. I have created a local variable called userId and assigned 1 to it and I am wondering if is possible to somehow set the div to left align if `userId === 1`, which will be the case. 
I've tried reading the react docs on conditional rendering but I don' believe that is what I'm looking for as they all deal with rendering whereas the div that I want to align is being returned by an export function so the render function isn't used.

```js
export function MessageRow({ message, fetch }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <div align="right" className="Message-Body">
        <div className="Message-row-header">{message.user}</div>
        <div>{message.content}</div>
        <div className="muted-text">
          (Sent: {new Date(message.timestamp).toUTCString()})
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            className="block"
            onClick={() => messageService.delete(message.id).then(fetch)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
          <button className="block">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is what I currently have and was thinking of trying a function like below but I am unsure how I would then get it to apply to the div.

```js
function checkMessageUserID(userId) {
  if (userId === 1) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Of course it is. Set a class based on the condition and align the class of whatever element based off this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can return JSX from the function and call the function inside return.

```
function checkMessageUserID(userId) {
    if (userId === 1) {
      <div align="right"  className="Message-Body">
    } 
    else{
      <div align="left"  className="Message-Body">
    }
}
```

Then inside return call {checkMessageUserID()}

2) You can also use ternary operator inside your render.

```
<div align = {userID == 1 ? "right" : "left"}  className="Message-Body">
```

Comment: When using your first solution I get and error for the lines below the if and the else, the error reads "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression".

Answer (score 1):

It is still being used from a render() point of view though, no?

So you could still do what you want:

```
return (
  <div><br />
  {userId !== 1 ?
    <div align="right" className="Message-Body">
    :
    <div align="left" className="Message-Body">
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional rendering works the same for `functional` as well as `stateful` components.

Working code snippet below.

```
<div align={userId === 1 ? 'left' : 'right' } className="Message-Body">
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Hard to believe it was as simple as this, haha!

Answer (score 0):

You could do any of the above, or what I would recommend is, you create two styling classnames, you can call them 'left/right-message' or 'mine/otherPerson-message' and you can assign align: 'left/right' to each, you can even assign different colors for that chat feel, you'd achieve this simply by doing:

```
<div className={userId === 1 ? "left-message" : "right-message" >
...
</div>
```